# What is difference between clang -O1 and opt -O1?

Tags: optimization, clang, llvm

What is the difference between `clang -O1` and `opt -O1`?
I observed that these two commands behave in a significantly different way.

### Context

I would like to test LLVM optimization passes. More specifically, I would like to pick a subset of `-O1` passes so that 1) the subset's performance is as good as the whole `-O1`, and 2) the selected passes are easy to reason about their correctness.

To test the performance of subset, I wrote a shell script like:

```
clang -o a.bc -emit-llvm -c a.c
opt (..., optmizations like -adce, ...) a.bc >a.opt.bc
clang -o a a.opt.bc
```

After a lot of tries, I figured out that:

```
clang -o a.bc -emit-llvm -c a.c
opt -O1 a.bc >a.opt.bc
clang -o a a.opt.bc
```

and
    clang -O1 -o a a.c

emit significantly different binary. The latter is much more efficient, for e.g., for an example program the former takes 49 secs to run, while the latter takes 29 secs.

### Tried Approaches

- I searched what does it mean for `clang -O1`, and found some references like [Clang optimization levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548023/clang-optimization-levels), but the article is really about `opt`, not `clang`.
- I tried to find official documentation for `clang`, but it was unfruitful.
- I tried to understand `clang` source code, but I could not...

### Found Facts

- I tried with

  clang -o a.bc -emit-llvm -c a.c
  opt -mem2reg -O1 a.bc >a.opt.bc
  clang -o a a.opt.bc

since a reference([Clang optimization levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548023/clang-optimization-levels)) said that `opt -O1` does not contain `mem2reg` pass. It helped to close some gap, but not completely. (49 secs -> 40 secs) That means, I guess, `clang -O1` performs some preliminary optimizations, such as `mem2reg`, before `-O1` does something else.

- I tried with

  clang -o a.bc -emit-llvm -c a.c
  opt -mem2reg -O1 a.bc >a.opt.bc
  clang -O1 -o a a.opt.bc

since I expect some target-dependent optimizations after LLVM IR passes. Actually it worked. (40 secs -> 26 secs, even faster than just `clang -O1`'s 29 secs)

### Conclusion

In conclusion, I guess there is a pre- and post- LLVM IR passes in `clang -O1` which is not present in `opt -O1`. So is there anyone who knows the difference between `clang -O1` and `opt -O1`? Any reference to official docs or source code, or ways to solve my initial problem will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can print all the passes (and information about transformations done by those passes) which the code goes through when using `clang` as follows:

`clang -O1 -Rpass=.* code.c`

To do the same with `opt`, you can use:

`opt -O1 -debug-pass=Arguments code.c`

Also this might help: [Which optimization does LLVM perform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656156/which-optimization-does-llvm-perform)

Comment: `-Rpass=.*` in clang does not work for me. `-mllvm -debug-pass=Arguments` would work.